# Joomla - 500 - Internal server error on file opening

Tags: iis, joomla, internal

I' am working with Joomla 2.5.8 running on IIS 7.5. When I uploading new files to the server, It uploads successfully but when I link that file to my article and view it in the front end. I' am getting an error (500 - Internal server error, Also see the first attached image).

I have tested with Mod Rewrite ON and OFF but still doesn't work. From my IIS Error Message Screen I can see error occurs in Mod Rewrite (Also see the second attached image).

Been working on this for the past 2 days. Any help will be apreciated...!

[500 - Internal server error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEPJN.jpg)

Comment: check the error log, and also try removing `.htaccess` file to see what happens. check if rewrite module is enabled for iis

Comment: Am on IIS, IIS doesn't have htaccess. I have checked the web-config for IIS. Seems to be okay as instructed in Joomla Docs. I' am still facing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. In my IIS web.config, It was stripping out pdf from the incoming urls. Thats why it was giving 500 error.